# :deep() syntax with nested scss rules

Tags: vue.js, sass, dart-sass, vue-sfc

I am trying to migrate some Vue.js Single File Components from `::v-deep` syntax to `:deep()`, as described [here](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0023-scoped-styles-changes.md#deep-selectors). However, I am not sure how to make it work with **nested** SCSS rules with `&__*`. Rules without `&__*` work just fine.

The SCSS compiler we use is [dart-sass](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass).

## Example

For example, having this original snippet:

```
::v-deep .wrapper {
    display: flex;

    &__element {
        display: block
    }
}
```

Correctly compiles the code to

```
[data-v-S0m3Ha5h] .wrapper__element {
    display: block;
}
```

And throws a warning: `[@vue/compiler-sfc] ::v-deep usage as a combinator has been deprecated. Use :deep(<inner-selector>) instead.`

### `:deep()` in top-level rule

I have tried converting it to `:deep()` like this:

```
:deep(.wrapper) {
    display: flex;

    &__element {
        display: block
    }
}
```

which results in a compiler error, because [`:deep(wrapper)__element` is not a valid selector](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/issues/1754).

### `:deep()` in the nested rule

So I moved the `:deep` to the nested rule:

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;

    :deep(&__element) {
        display: block
    }
}
```

which compiles without errors, but produces botched css:

```
.wrapper[data-v-S0m3Ha5h] &__element {/* ... */}
```

---

## Question

How can I use nested `&__*` rules with `:deep()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sass apparently doesn't allow the selector argument list of `:deep`(or of any other pseudo-class) to be nested because of the reason you mentioned, but there are a couple workarounds.

#### Workaround 1: Split up the Sass styles

Split up the styles so that `:deep`'s selector list is not nested:

```html
<!-- MyParent.vue -->
<style scoped lang="scss">
:deep(.wrapper) {
    display: flex;
}
:deep(.wrapper__element) {
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-deep-selector-in-sass-rbu7za?file=src%2FApp.vue)

#### Workaround 2: Split up the class names

Break up the BEM class names (from `wrapper__element` to `__element`) so that parent selectors are not necessary:

```html
<!-- MyComponent.vue -->
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="__element">...</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

or augment `wrapper__element` with an additional `__element` class (if you can ignore the repetition):

```html
<!-- MyComponent.vue -->
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper__element __element">...</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

For some reason, this scenario requires `:deep` to based on a selector (e.g., `root` in the example below):

```html
<!-- MyParent.vue -->
<template>
    <div class="root">
        <MyComponent />
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.root:deep(.wrapper) {
    display: flex;

    .__element {
        display: block;
    }
}
</style>
```

```html
<!-- MyComponent.vue -->
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>.wrapper</h1>

    <!-- Add __element class here  (and optionally remove wrapper__element) -->
    <div class="wrapper__element __element">
      <h1>.wrapper__element</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-deep-selector-in-sass?file=src%2FApp.vue)